# New iPhone 6s lost the new photos after synching to iTunes (restore old back up of iPhone 5s)

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, icloud, photos

I have new iPhone 6s with lots of holiday photos. After synching to itunes, with only intention to sync the contacts, iTunes prompt me 2 question: Set as new iphone and recover old back up. I chose the latter, and lost all my new photos.

I have tried few software to recover data directly from ios, itunes back up. None of it working. I disabled icloud, so theres no back up in icloud too.

Is there anyway to recover my lost photos?

Answer (score 1):

Whichever you chose, you should have done it the minute you got the new phone, then the transition would have been seamless.

There's now no way to recover the intermediate data, unless it it was also backed up on iCloud.